# Linux pattern searching

Tags: linux, text-processing

If I have a file with lots of directory info like:

```
/home/svdev/src/lib
/home/dev/project/doc
/home/server/etc
```

I want to get the directory name next to "/home" directory. So for this set of data, my output should be svdev, dev, server

Comment: How is the data in the file, is it in one line, or one entry per line?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -e 's,^/home/,,' -e 's,/.*,,' file
svdev
dev
server
```

This uses `sed` to first delete the initial `/home/` path, and then everything that comes after the first `/` in the remainder of the line.

I'm using commas as the delimiter to the `s` command in `sed` to avoid [the leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Another approach with `sed` is to replace the whole line with the second thing between `/`:

```
$ sed 's,/[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*,\1,' file
svdev
dev
server
```

Comment: @BISWAJITMAHARANA In a delete comment you mentioned that your actual data does not look as in the question. Could you please update your question with the actual data?

Answer (score 3):

A very crude way of doing it using `cut` and specifying slash as delimiter:

```
cut -d "/" -f 3 thefile
```

Output:

```
svdev
dev
server
```

Assuming the directories all start with `/home`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the sub-directories of /home

```
find /home -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```

if the paths are the content of a file,

```
awk -F '/' '{printf "%s, ",$3}' file.txt
```